# Display validation error in DataGridCell tooltip

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid which displays types that implement IDataErrorInfo.  As expected when the validation fails the row gets the red exclamation mark and the invalid cell gets the red highlight.
[image]

This is all well and good; however, I want the validation error message to display in the tooltip of the invalid cell so the user has some indication of what is wrong.  I presently have:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                                Path=(Validation.Errors[0].ErrorContent}"/>
     </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

This approach works for `TextBox` but not for `DataGridCell`.  What is the difference?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have something similiar in a project I'm working on right now, and it goes something like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.ToolTip"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                                Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
     </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

Comment: typo - should be: Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at this MSDN log post:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bethmassi/2008/06/27/displaying-data-validation-messages-in-wpf/

Follow its instructions to create a textbox cell editing template that will look something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="errTemplate">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
      <Setter Property="ToolTip"
              Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                     Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then, you can use it in your datagrid by setting the EditingElementStyle like so:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Variable" 
                    Binding="{Binding Variable, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                    EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource errTemplate}"/>
```

It is important to use the data trigger so that you can support a standard tool tip as well as a tool tip when there is an error as explained in this post:

[Tooltip Not Showing Up When No Validation Error WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324855/tooltip-not-showing-up-when-no-validation-error-wpf)