# Tooltip Not Showing Up When No Validation Error WPF

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, tooltip, idataerrorinfo

I searched and did not see a solution.

I can only get the validation to show the tooltip if I do not set a tooltip in the combo box tooltip property. I would like to see the validation error tooltip when one is present otherwise show the tooltip from the combobox property. The validation tooltip shows up fine when I remove the text from the tooltip property (i.e. from the property panel for the combo box).

The XAML in Application.Resources (App.XAML)for the tooltip to show the validation error is

```
    <Style x:Key="StandardComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I also use a validation template for the Combobox as follows. This is in the UserControl.Resources section within the user control cs file.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="comboBoxValidationTemplate">
    <DockPanel Name="myDockPanel">
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3">
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="MyAdorner" />
        </Border>
        <TextBlock Text="*" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18" Foreground="Red" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The control itself is defined as follows. Note that there are other references not defined here (but hopefully not pertinent - feel free to let me know if questions).

```
        <ComboBox x:Name="ExposureTime" SelectedValuePath="Content"
        Text="{Binding ExposureTime, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" IsEditable="True" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource comboBoxValidationTemplate}"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" FontSize="18" Margin="136,47,462,0" Height="27" VerticalAlignment="Top" GotFocus="ComboBox_GotFocus_1" LostFocus="ComboBox_LostFocus_1" PreviewTextInput="ExposureTime_PreviewTextInput" Opacity="{Binding BackgroundOpacity, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontWeight="Thin" Style="{DynamicResource StandardComboBoxStyle}" SelectedValue="{Binding Mode=OneWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" IsTextSearchEnabled="False" ToolTip="My tooltip test.">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="0.05"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="0.1"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="0.2" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="1" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="2" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="5" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="10" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="20" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="60" />
        <ComboBox.IsEnabled >
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiBooleanConverter}">
                <Binding Path="NotPerformingExposure" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>Th
                <Binding Path="NotPerformingFocusTest" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </ComboBox.IsEnabled>
    </ComboBox>
```

Thanks!
Buck

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your style triggers you set the tooltip to the Validation error when you have an error. You can do the same when you don't have an error by manipulating the `Value` property of the `Trigger`

```
<Style x:Key="StandardComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="My tooltip test." />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

On another note I'd recommend changing `Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent` to `Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent`

Comment: Great solution, but what would I do if I want to apply this to different combo boxes, each of which has a different tooltip.  I.e. Combobox1 has tooltip "I am one", and ComboBox2 has tooltip "I am #2".  I'm guessing something like <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Tooltip}" /> but can't get it working!